# Product limit proof, stuck.

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to understand the proof of the product of the limits by following this explanation, I understand it up to the point where it states that

$ 0 < |x-a| < \delta_1 $

implies

$ |f(x) -L| < |\epsilon/(2M)| $

[image]

Why is epsilon divided by 2M?
I understand that this is a different epsilon from our original one and it is smaller then the original one by why divide the original one by 2M ?
Why not just 2 ?
What am I missing ?

Comment: They do that so that at the end you just get $\epsilon$ (for educational reasons, because that's how you define the limit). Notice that you can do it (supposing $M\neq0$) since for the limit of $f$ you can find a delta for whatever $\epsilon>0$, so in particular for $\epsilon / 2|M|>0$.

Comment: I'm upvoting it, not because I answered it, but because I think this is an interesting question. As for myself, I remember that time when I was a student and wondering why my teacher was making so much effort to guess if he was needing an $\varepsilon/3$ or an $\varepsilon/4$ at a certain stage of a proof. The fact is I personally never cared and wasn't shocked in any way to get $47\varepsilon$ by the end of my attempts, but some people like it otherwise, and it deserves to be explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact people in these proofs with epsilon involved like to arrive at the conclusion with a nice $\varepsilon$, not $2\varepsilon$ or $3\varepsilon$ or $\varepsilon/2$ but $1$ unity of it.

So to get to that they divide it in the way by the appropriate various quantities, and in the grand final, when all is added, miracle we get $1\times\varepsilon$, applause !

Yet in theory it does not matter, if you can prove that $|x-a|<\delta\Rightarrow|f(x)-L|<1000\varepsilon$ or even $178437800034653256436\varepsilon$ as soon as it is a **CONSTANT** multiple of $\varepsilon$ you have proved continuity.

Here $L$ and $M$ are constants so it does not matter, they can divide the epsilon by it, if they desire so.

So the method of *cutting epsilons* is more an aesthetic thing than anything else.

---

Answer to comment :

The transcript of $f(x)\to L$ is : "*for any $\varepsilon_1$ we can find $\delta_1$*" so they decide to choose $\varepsilon_1=\varepsilon/2M$.

The transcript of $g(x)\to M$ is : "*for any $\varepsilon_2$ we can find $\delta_2$*" so they decide to choose $\varepsilon_2=\varepsilon/2L$.

Finally for $|x-a|<\delta=min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$ they get $|f(x)g(x)-LM|< M\varepsilon_1+L\varepsilon_2=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon$

If we simply choose $\varepsilon_1=\varepsilon_2=\varepsilon$ we would arrive to $|x-a|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)g(x)-LM|< M\varepsilon_1+L\varepsilon_2=(M+L)\varepsilon$ which also works.

They have latency to choose *any* epsilon so they do it in order to get a clean $|f(x)g(x)-LM|<\varepsilon$ as stated by their initial claim.

The logic is that since you have the right to choose any $\varepsilon$ you want, then let's take one that conveniently arrange further calculations. I think that what puzzles you is that they never mention $\varepsilon_1$ and $\varepsilon_2$, which are the ones you have choice latency on. Instead of that they directly use the $\varepsilon$ they focus on since the beginning. This is why I detailled it in my answer above so nothing is hidden or implicit.

Comment: So when they say it implies it they just mean they decided ?
When they say implies I assume that there is some kind of logic behind it.

Comment: I have detailled the process, to make it clearer.